# problem in navigate to another page in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make a login page that navigates to another page when the `Submit` button is clicked using ReactJS. but I encountered a few problems:

1. it looks like the event handler function gets called right away when the page loads because the `console.log('clicked')` appears in the developer tools before I do anything
2. when I actually clicked the `Submit` button, the page doesn't change.
3. when the page changes (or loads), there's a warning in the developer tools saying

```
No routes matched location "/"  

    in Routes (created by App)
    in App
```

although there are already paths for `/` and `/dashboard` in the `<Routes>` in `App.js`

here's my code (and here's the [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/great-matsumoto-1d74ry?file=/src/App.js)):

```
// ./App.js
import { HashRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Login from "./components/Login";
import Dashboard from "./components/Dashboard";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Login />} />
        </Routes>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

// ./components/Login.js
import { Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const Login = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleClick = (e) => {
    console.log("clicked");
    navigate("/dashboard");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <h2>The Login page</h2>
        <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleClick()}>
          Submit
        </Button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;

// ./components/Dashboard.js
import React from "react";

const Dashboard = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>This is the Dashboard page</h2>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Dashboard;
```

Comment: `onClick` takes a function. Try `onClick={handleClick}`

Comment: thanks. the code inside the event handler now only runs after I clicked the button. but why is it when any of the page loads (either the Login and Dashboard page), there is a warning saying `No routes matched location "/dashboard"  

    in Routes (created by App)
    in App` and `No routes matched location "/"  

    in Routes (created by App)
    in App`. why is that? and is that a problem?

Comment: Perhaps because you're wrapping all your `<Route>` with `<Routes>`. Try just a single `<Routes>` and put both `<Route>` inside of it. See example https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/components/routes

Answer (score 2):

It’s because you are directly calling function
`onClick = {()=> handleClick(“send anything here”)}`

Answer (score 0):

When ever you call like this `onClick = {handleClick()}` it will immediately trigger that function , but you want that function call after event then you can use `onClick = {()=> handleClick(“send anything here”)}`
And if you want to pass event along with parameter then use this `onClick = {(event)=> handleClick(event,“send anything here”)}`
If you don't have to pass parameter then use this `onClick = {handleClick}`